# Running a program on uninstall

Tags: wix

I want to run a program when my software is being un-installed, it is a simple form that should gather some feedback on why people are un-installing my software.

I found some WiX examples that works to some degree.

It works pretty fine with a standard windows program (notepad), but when I try to run my own program, it does not work. I think the problems is that the program is removed, before it has been run.

I have tried to print the logs, but they did not give me any clues of what to do.

My code so far:

```
<CustomAction Id="LaunchFeedBackForm" 
 ExeCommand="notepad.exe" Directory="INSTALLDIR" 
 Return="asyncWait" >REMOVE="ALL"</CustomAction>


<InstallExecuteSequence>
    <Custom Action="LaunchFeedBackForm" After="InstallValidate"/>
</InstallExecuteSequence>
```

So I need in some way the un-install process to halt or what ever, until the user has closed the feedback form. After the form has been closed, it should continue and remove all software including the feedback form program.

Answer (score 5):

The way you'd like to get user's feedback seems not that natural to me. If I understand you correctly, you'd like to show this feedback form and wait while a user fills it in, and later on continue with uninstallation, right?

To my own experience, when a user decides to uninstall software, he/she would like it to get uninstalled as quickly and clear as possible. Bringing a "must fill" form in front of them would only negatively affect the user experience. Moreover, as you can see, it is more difficult from the technical point of view. I suppose you've also thought about passing this feedback on to your side, right? Is it emailing the info entered by user? How do you ensure the email gets sent?

Alternatively, you can have this form online on a certain web page of your site and start it when the uninstall is done (NOT in progress). In this way, you don't annoy the user blocking the uninstall process.

So, I would do the following:

- have a custom action that starts a browser with a URL you need
- the installation program SHOULD NOT WAIT for this to complete

BTW, do not expect lots of feedback - people rarely bother spending some time to give feedback :)

Comment: Hi, Good input. I should properly go with the browser solution. It is only in the trail version, that it was suppose to be a optional form. I know it will not give me a lot of usable feedback (most likely garbage), but I hope that just once in a while, a person would give me some good feedback, on why my app. suck.

Comment: Then try to make your feedback form do not suck :) And good luck!

Comment: This is a business decision and a good one. and you are totally wong here.

He is leaving and you don't care if you piss him off just a bit more. In fact you want the angry people to tell you truthfully why they your program suck. At the time i used this technique i got usefull information. I can't convert them into customers but maybe others.

Answer (score 1):

If your EXE is in the MSI, try using the FileKey attribute: http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix2/wix_xsd_customaction.htm

For example, if your EXE is defined like this:

```
<File Id="FeedbackExe" Name="FeedbackExe.exe"/>
```

you can use:

```
<CustomAction Id="LaunchFeedBackForm" 
 FileKey="FeedbackExe" Execute="deferred"
 Return="asyncWait">REMOVE="ALL"</CustomAction>
```

You can also try creating an uninstall log to see what happens with the custom action:

```
msiexec.exe /x <ProductCode> /L*V "C:\uninstall.log"
```

where you use your actual ProductCode.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your reply. I have tried that, but is does not work either. I just seems like it is not run at all, but I can see the action in the log. I works with programs not included in the msi file, but to leave a program after uninstall on target machine, is pretty yucky.

Comment: If it runs right after InstallValidate it can use installed files because they haven't been removed yet. You can try storing the file in Binary table, but I don't think that this is the problem. Try debugging the EXE (attach to its process) and see what happens. Also, try posting the full log so we can take a look.

Comment: Hi Again, I went with a browser solution (opening a webpage). This was also pretty complicated, had to run cmd start .... to get it to work. But I think  Yan Sklyarenko was correct in his feedback, and therefore choose this solution. But thanks for your reply.  :-)

Answer (score 0):

> So I need in some way the un-install process to halt or what ever,
>   until the user has closed the feedback form. After the form has been
>   closed, it should continue and remove all software including the
>   feedback form program.

To do this one would set After="InstallValidate"

```
<InstallExecuteSequence>
<Custom Action="InstallCustomLogic" After="InstallFinalize" />
<Custom Action="UninstallCustomLogic" 
After="InstallValidate" >
NOT UPGRADINGPRODUCTCODE) AND (REMOVE="ALL")
</Custom>
</InstallExecuteSequence>
```

Set Return attribute to check so that the installer will halt until the specified executable returns.

```
<CustomAction Id="UninstallCustomLogic"               
Directory="INSTALLFOLDER"              
ExeCommand="[INSTALLFOLDER]\RetailConnectCustomLogic.exe uninstall"
Return="check"              
/>
```

This is useful in the event where you need to run something located in the program directory before uninstalling the program. One could also set the attribute to **ignore** if it doesn't return 0